# I got an error when to import stock data into r

Tags: r, stock

Here are the codes that I use:

```
library(quantmod)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)


mdate <- "2015-10-30"
edate <- "2016-01-07"
tickers4 <- c("RTL","RTM")

data <- do.call("cbind", lapply(seq_along(tickers4), function(i){
  try_var <- try(getSymbols(tickers4[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE))
  if(inherits(try_var, "try-error")) {
    i <- i + 1
  } else{
    getSymbols(tickers4[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE)   
  }
}
)
)

# Transpose data.frame: td_data => data.frame
td_data <- within(data.frame(price_var = row.names(t(data)), t(data), row.names = NULL), 
                  {
                    ticker_cd <- as.factor(gsub("[.].*", "", price_var))
                    price_var <- as.factor(gsub(".*[.]", "", price_var))
                  }
)

# Re-order vectors; keep complete cases: td_data_o => data.frame
td_data_o <- td_data[complete.cases(td_data), 
                     c(names(td_data)[sapply(td_data, is.factor)],  
                       names(td_data)[sapply(td_data, function(x){!is.factor(x)})])]

# Reshape: abc => data.frame
abc4 <- do.call("cbind", split(td_data_o, td_data_o$price_var))
```

When I run these codes, abc4 must have 288 variables, but 336 variables are created. 
The value of 289th and 290th are "X2". From 300th, all the other values are "2". 
I found that it was caused by "RTL" in ticker4. This ticker's value do not exist between mdate and edate. 
How can I skip a ticker that do not exist when to import stock data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 library(quantmod)
# Start date: mdate => character
mdate <- "2015-10-30"

# End date: edate => character
edate <- "2016-01-07"

# tickers4 => character vector: 
tickers4 <- c("RTL","RTM","RTM","RYN","RYU","SAH","SBS","SCCO","SCHC","SCM","SHO","SJI","SLX","SNA","SWN","SWZ","TCO","TDF","THG")

# Create empty list to store xts objects: dlist => list
dlist <- vector("list", length(unique(tickers4)))

# Use quatmod api to retrieve stock data from yahoo finance, dlist => list of xts objects
dlist <- lapply(seq_along(unique(tickers4)), function(i){
        res <- NULL
        try_var <- try(getSymbols(tickers4[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE))
        if(inherits(try_var, "try-error")) {
          i <- i + 1
        } else{
          res <- getSymbols(tickers4[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE)   
        }
      return(res)
    }
  )

# Filter out null values from the list, column bind the results: data => xts object
data <- do.call("cbind", Filter(Negate(is.null), dlist))

# Transpose data.frame: td_data => data.frame
td_data <- within(data.frame(price_var = row.names(t(data)), t(data), row.names = NULL), 
                  {
                    ticker_cd <- as.factor(gsub("[.].*", "", gsub("[.]\\d+$", "", price_var)))
                    price_var <- as.factor(gsub(".*[.]", "", gsub("[.]\\d+$", "", price_var)))
                  }
)

# Re-order vectors; keep complete cases: td_data_o => data.frame
td_data_o <- td_data[complete.cases(td_data), 
                     c(names(td_data)[sapply(td_data, is.factor)],  
                       names(td_data)[sapply(td_data, function(x){!is.factor(x)})])]

# Reshape: abc => data.frame
abc4 <- do.call("cbind", split(td_data_o, td_data_o$price_var))
```

Comment: Thank you so much again. Unfortunately I got another error when I use: "tickers4 <- c("RTL","RTM","RTM","RYN","RYU","SAH","SBS","SCCO","SCHC","SCM","SHO","SJI","SLX","SNA","SWN","SWZ","TCO","TDF","THG")" The error is "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 17"

Comment: Hm..Do they work in your R? I got same error "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 17"

Comment: @DongchulPark Try above code. They worked using your original sample tickers. When you change the underlying data thats a new question. The big problem is that you have duplicate tickers in your ticker4 vector. This causes names to be appended with .1 or .2. This wont be a problem now.  Try the above code and upvote it and accept it if it does what you require.

Comment: @DongchulPark is it working for you now. This code should be robust to missing data and even to duplicates in your ticker vector.

Comment: OMG. It really works! Thank you so much. You are really something. I was going to upvote all your answer whether or not it works. Thank you again for your time and great work.

Comment: Lol thank you, sorry it took some time to get to the answer you needed. Let me know if you have anymore problems. Now all you need to do is to analyse the data ;)